# Can I assign value to variable or parameter after the execution code is defined?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, local-variables

I have a quite large script which is shrunk and simplified in this question.The overall principal is that I have some code that need to be run several times with only small adjustments for every iteration. The script is built with a major loop that has several subloops in it. Today the whole select-statement is hard coded in the loops. My thought was that I could write the select-statement once and only let the parts that needs to be changed for every loop be the only thing that changes in the loop. The purpose is easier maintaining.

Example of the script:

```
declare
    @i1 int,
    @i2 int,
    @t nvarchar(50),
    @v nvarchar(50),
    @s nvarchar(max)

set @i1 = 1

while @i1 < 3
begin

    if @i1 = 1
    begin

        set @i2 = 1
        set @t = 'Ansokningsomgang'

        set @s = '
            select ' + @v + '_Ar,count(*) as N
            from (
                select left(' + @v + ',4) as ' + @v + '_Ar
                from Vinnova_' + @t + '
                ) a
            group by ' + @v + '_Ar
            order by ' + @v + '_Ar
            '
        
        while @i2 < 4
        begin

            if @i2 = 1
            begin

                set @v = 'diarienummer'

                exec sp_executesql
                    @stmt = @s,
                    @params = N'@tab as nvarchar(50), @var as nvarchar(50)',
                    @tab = @t, @var = @v

            end
            else if @i2 = 2
            begin

                set @v = 'utlysning_diarienummer'

                exec sp_executesql
                    @stmt = @s,
                    @params = N'@tab as nvarchar(50), @var as nvarchar(50)',
                    @tab = @t, @var = @v

            end
            else if @i2 = 3
            begin

                set @v = 'utlysning_program_diarienummer'

                exec sp_executesql
                    @stmt = @s,
                    @params = N'@tab as nvarchar(50), @var as nvarchar(50)',
                    @tab = @t, @var = @v

            end

            set @i2 = @i2 + 1

        end

    end
    else
        
        print('Nr: ' + cast(@i1 as char))

    set @i1 = @i1 + 1

end
```

This script doesn't work. It runs through but have no outputs. If I `declare @v` above the declaration of `@s` it works, but then I need to `declare @s` for every time I need to change the value for @v. Then there is no point in doing this.

`@i1` iterates far more times than what is shown here.

The else statement to "if @i1" doesn't exist in the real script. It replaces a bunch of subloops that run for every value that is aloud for @i1 in this example.

I also tried to just execute @s like:

```
exec(@s)
```

in every loop. Same result.

So what am I missing?

Database engine is MS SQL Server.

Comment: WHat you have there is very dangerous. It's wide open to injection attacks. Honestly, I wouldn't be surprised if what we have here is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Looping is almost always the wrong solution in SQL, as it's a set based language. What is the *real* problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: Also, I suspect that the reason it doesn't return anything is because you are concatenating `@v` to your variable `@s`, but `@v` has the value `NULL`. `{anything} + NULL = NULL`

Comment: I need to run almost the same select-statement over a number of tables and in every table I need to check a various number of variables by count. The variables have different names in every table and is in various number from table to table.

Comment: *"The variables have different names in every table"* What do you mean by this? Tables can't contain variables.

Comment: Yes, I suspected the NULL-part. But I don't know how to solve that without ending up with a bunch of hard coded select-statements again?

Comment: Sorry for my slappy use of words. With variables I mean columns/attributes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233931/discussion-between-marjer-and-larnu).

Comment: SAmple data and expected results is going to likely help us help you here. WE'll need the sample data in DDL and DML statements.

Comment: Sorry. Due to national laws I'm not allowed to share the data. I now what I'm sending is not what you asked for. Atleast it's an example of what I'm trying to get. I'll just see if I can figure out how to add my example file (xlsx) to my question?

Comment: *" Due to national laws I'm not allowed to share the data"* I never asked for your data, I asked for **sample** data. And no, don't post a link to a spreadsheet, post DML and DML statements in your question, as I mentioned.

Comment: The DML command I'm using here is a select-statement (I know that is discussed however select is considered a DML-statement or not).  I don't change anything in the database structure (no DDL:s). But I think that you are asking something else since all this emerges from my example code above. So I guess that my lack of deeper knowledge here has led me to the end of the road. Thank you anyway for your answers. At least it helped me to get my suspicious about the NULL-part mainly confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

Your parallel-structured tables are not 'normalized' to any degree,
and you are now suffering the consequence.  Typically, the best
approach is to go ahead and make the data more normalized before you
take any other action.

Dynamic sql could work for making this task easier, and it is okay
as long as it's an ad-hoc task that hopefully you use to begin
building permanent tables in the name of making your various
parallel tables obsolete.  It is not okay if it is part of a
regular process because someone could enter in some malicious
code into one of your table values and do some damage.  This is
particularly true in your case because your use of `left`
functions imply that you're columns are character based.

Here's some code to put your data in more normal form.  It can be
made more normal after this, so it would only be the first step.
But it gets you to the point where using it for your purpose is
far easier, and so hopefully will motivate you to redesign.

```
-- plug in the parallel tables you want to normalize
declare @tablesToNormalize table (id int identity(1,1), tbl sysname);
insert @tablesToNormalize values ('Ansokningsomgang', 'Ansokningsomgang2');

-- create a table that will hold the restructured data
create table ##normalized (
    tbl sysname,
    rowKey int, -- optional, but needed if restructure is permanent
    col sysname,
    category varchar(50),
    value varchar(50)
);

-- create template code to restructure and insert a table's data 
-- into the normalized table (notice the use of @tbl as a string, 
-- not as a variable)
declare @templateSql nvarchar(max) = '
    insert      ##normalized
    select      tbl = ''Vinnova_@tbl'',
                rowKey = t.somePrimaryKey, -- optional, but needed if restructure is permanent
                ap.col,
                category = left(ap.value, 4),
                ap.value
    from        Vinnova_@tbl t
    cross apply (values
                    (''diarienummer'', diarienummer),
                    (''utlysning_diarienummer'', utlysning_diarienummer),
                    (''utlysning_program_diarienummer'', utlysning_program_diarienummer)
                    // ... and so on (much better than writing a nested loop for ever row)
                ) ap (col, value)
';

-- loop the table names and run the template (notice the 'replace' function)
declare @id int = 1;
while @id <= (select max(id) from @tablesToNormalize) 
begin
    declare @tbl sysname = (select tbl from @tablesToNormalize where id = @id);
    declare @sql nvarchar(max) = replace(@templateSql, '@t', @tbl); 
    exec (@tbl);
end
```

Now that your data is in a more normal form, code for your purpose
is much simpler, and the output far cleaner.

```
select      tbl, col, category, n = count(value)
from        ##normalized
group by    tbl, col, category
order by    tbl, col, category;
```